# What type of inheritance allows this

Tags: django, django-models

I have 2 simple models; a "JobInfo" model and a "Contact" model.

```
class JobInfo(models.Model):
    client = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=CLIENT_CHOICES)
    job_number = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True, blank=True, null=True)
    page_type = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=PT_CHOICES)
    contact = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=CONTACT_CHOICES?)

    def __unicode__ (self):
    return self.job_number

    class Admin: 
        pass

class Contact(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64, unique=False, blank=True, null=True)
    position = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=CLIENT_CHOICES)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=15, unique=False, blank=True, null=True)
    fax = models.CharField(max_length=15, unique=False, blank=True, null=True)
    email = models.EmailField()

    def __unicode__ (self):
    return self.name

    class Admin: 
        pass
```

Can my "Contact" objects (from Contact Model) be choices for the contact field in the "JobInfo" model? I'd like to be able to select contacts in my JobInfo form and have those Contact properties available to display in the same template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to create a [relationship](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/models/fields/#foreignkey), right?

So the contact field on your JobInfo model should look like this:

```
contact = models.ForeignKey('Contact')
```

Answer (score 0):

could you try

```
class JobInfo(models.Model):
    ...
    contact = Contact(models.Model)
```

Comment: contact = Contact(models.Model)
NameError: name 'Contact' is not defined ...thanks though

Comment: looks like it's not inheritance that I'm looking for. Foreign Key might do the trick. testing now....